# Undefined variable: _SESSION in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I upgrade my `codeigniter` version from 2.1.0 to 2.1.3 from cpanel installatron. Also I integrated tank auth library with `codeigniter`. I started `session_start()` in `index.php` file.

Now I am getting Undefined variable: `_SESSION` error.

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you haven't initiliazed the `session library`?

Try to:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

That happens to me sometimes.

Comment: @Neel tell us what was the issue!

Answer (score 2):

In `Codeigniter 2.X` and earlier you cannot use `$_SESSION` directly before starting session manually.

Instead you can retrieve all session data in a variable and use it like your `$_SESSION` variable. You can do it as bellow:

```
$my_session_variable = $this->session->all_userdata();
```

Here our own variable `$my_session_variable` will become a copy of `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1):

check your file that your file is not utf-8 or if you need utf-8 use utf-8 without BOM.
i hope this help you.

Comment: Is your OS windows. if you have windows , you can open file with `notepad.exe` and when save as file prompted save asci or utf-8.

Comment: Thanks aya, but not getting solution.